# Hashtag implementation | Angular |

Tags: angular, angular-material, hashtag

I have below code in **HTML**: have used Angular material to create a textbox using form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm" #f="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="postField">
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Say something.." name="postBody" 
            formControlName="postBody" type="text" [ngModel]="postBody | hashtag" 
                (ngModelChange)="postBody=$event" >
                </textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br/>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isDisabled"> Post </button>
    </form>
```

Im trying to implement hashtag functionality like in twitter/fb where while writing a post and using #something... the text along with hash gets highlighted to blue. Trying to implementing using pipes. Below is the ts file.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'hashtag' })
export class HashtagPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}

    transform(text: string){
        let text1;
        if (text.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            const str = text.replace(/#/g, '<span class="highlighted"></span>');
            text1 = text;
        } else {
            text1 = text;
        }
        return text1;
    }
}
```

This isnt working. what changes are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Change the hashtag pipe transform method to

```
 transform(text: string){
        let text1;
        if (text.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            text1 = text + ' '; 
            const matches = text1.match(/#(.*?) /g);
            for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
              text1 = text1.replace(matches[i], '<span class="highlighted">' + matches[i] + '</span>');
            }
        } else {
            text1 = text;
        }
        return text1;
    }
```

Also, have a look at the following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iy46gj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhashtag.pipe.ts